# How merge post category and post id and save it to a custom field

Tags: wordpress

i have a front end form for post creation but i want there a field which says unique post id, this id is the combination of category and post id which is in database (because the post id is unique for every post).

**Example:**
post id= "135"
category = "A00Z"

is there any way to update the combined values of post id and category in the following way to a custom field with meta key "unique_post_id"

Unique post ID = "A00Z135"

Thanks

Comment: No need to create post id because it is auto increment fields in wp_posts and it automatically created , you can create simple post by using wp_insert_post function. Please see this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Comment: i dont want to create a post id i just want to merge the post id and the post category to another custom field, i know the post id is auto created on submission and they are auto incremental
thanks